# How to read csv from ftp using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sftp

I connected to a sftp and got a list of files successfully:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )

ssh.connect(Hostname, username=Username, password=Password)

ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
files = ftp.listdir()

dir_oi = "blah"
foi = ftp.listdir(dir_oi)
foi = [i for i in foi if '.csv' in i]
foi = [i for i in foi if not '.test.' in i]
len(foi)
```

and I get a list of 500+ csvs. I would like to read them to process, but am hitting a block.

```
remote_file = ( dir_oi +"/" + foi[0])
```

I tried `pd.read_csv(remote_file)` and other parimiko suggestions from SO to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I found this method worked

```
with ftp.open(remote_file) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep = '\t', header = None)
```

Comment: Well, that's what my answer to [Reading .csv file to memory from SFTP server using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56652280/850848) shows. If that works, please consider upvoting the posts. In any case, please do not post duplicate answers.